# how to set 2d dynamic array with specific values in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I create a 2D dynamic array (ary), and initialize all the element to -1 ,,, then i want to set array element with some values,, but it dose't work

```
int rowCount,t;

t=4; rowCount = t/3 + (t % 3 != 0);

int** ary = new int*[rowCount];
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i)
    ary[i] = new int[t];


for (int n = 0; n < rowCount*t; n++)
  *((int*)ary + t) = -1;

for(int m=0;m<rowCount;m++)
   for(int h=0;h<t;h++)
ary[m][h]=a[h];  // a is predefined array
```

Comment: At first glance, it appears that you have not initialized `rowCount` nor `t`. That would be a show-stopper.

Comment: i initialize them `t=4;`  `rowCount = t/3 + (t % 3 != 0);`

Comment: why the initialization is incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

If you analyze the following lines carefully, you'll realize that you are accessing memory out of bounds and the programs exhibits undefined behavior.

```
for (int n = 0; n < rowCount*t; n++)
  *((int*)ary + t) = -1;
```

The line

```
  *((int*)ary + t) = -1;
```

is wrong on the following counts.

1. You are casting an `int**` to an `int*`.
2. You have allocated memory using many calls to `new` but you are trying to treat it as though the data for all the `int`s were allocated using one call to `new`.

The simple fix is:

```
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
   for (int col = 0; col < t; ++col )
   {
      arr[row][col] = -1;
   }
}
```

You also have the option of allocating memory for all the `int`s using one call to `new`. In that case, you'll have to worry about mapping row and column to one index in rest of your code.

```
// Allocate memory in one chunk.
int* arr = new int[rowCount+t];

// Initialize values to -1.
for (int n = 0; n < rowCount*t; ++n )
{
   arr[n] = -1;
}
```